# Matlab get the line object from axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, inheritance, matlab-guide

I have created matlab gui using the guide where is one axis where I am plotting two lines using the function `plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)` so one line is connected with left y-axis and the second one with the right y-axis.

I have a fuction where I input just 'handles.axes1' and I get all the lines that are plotted in the axis and copy them to the new figure. The problem is that this doesnt work with the plotyy(...) I am getting just one line. This is my code (**hObject is a handles.axis that were selected**)

```
copyobj(get(hObject,'Child'), findobj(get(activeFigures(i),'Children'),'Type','Axes'));
```

If I use `findall(hObject)` I will get:

- Axes     (axes1)
- Text     (PlotyyDeleteProxy)
- Stair    (Plausible)
- Text     (Total ( Number of samples: 30947 ))
- Text     (Month)
- Text     (Number of Sapmles)
- Text

and stair plausible contains inly one line.

Answer (score 0):

`plotyy` actually creates two different axes over each other. You therefore need to copy the children from both axes into your new figure axes.

To find these axes either run

```
axes_handle_array=plotyy(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
```

or

```
axes_handle_array=findall(gcf,'type','axes')
```